# Error thrown Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array

Tags: errors

I try to pull up my website both normally and thru the wp-admin and both ways Error thrown  Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array comes up on the screen. I do not see any part of my site what is this and how can I fix it?Please help. I have no idea why

Comment: The error would have specified which file it occurred in. That will include the folder. You can use that to identify the plugin/theme responsible and contact the author for support.

Answer (score 1):

One of your plugin or your theme is throwing this error.

Best way to identify it is to look at the path of the file that is throwing this error. Should be something like `wp-content/plugins/xxx`. Then if you go to your Wordpress install, navigate to `wp-content/plugins` look for that folder and rename it, the plugin will be deactivated and the error shouldn't be thrown anymore. If the file is pointing to the `wp-content/themes/` folder then your active theme is at fault.

You should look to contact the developers of that plugin/theme for more help once you found out what exactly is causing this.